# Embed fonts via CSS; nothing seems to be working

Tags: css, fonts, embed

I've been through a slew of questions here and I'm not seeing why what I'm doing isn't working — but it isn't.  I want to use a couple nonstandard fonts in a website, embedded via css.

Here's what the CSS I got from FontSquirrel looks like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CrimsonRoman';
    src: url('Crimson-Roman-webfont.eot');
    src: url('Crimson-Roman-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('Crimson-Roman-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('Crimson-Roman-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('Crimson-Roman-webfont.svg#CrimsonRoman') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

Here's where it's referenced in my main css stylesheet:

```
p {
  margin: 0 0 9px;
  font-family: 'CrimsonRoman', Garamond, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

Everything's in the same directory right now, so I'm not even dealing with navigating through directories yet.  The "p" declaration itself seems to be working, because if I change the first term to "Crimson," the name the font has on my computer, it loads it fine (or if I switch it to any other font I have installed locally).  Whatever the problem is, I'm not seeing it.

Both sheets are linked successfully in my html doc, and the font's is linked before the main one.

I'm using Firefox to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turned out to be something in how Dreamweaver renders pages, or reads CSS, etc. I finally uploaded everything to the site so I could show a couple people what was going on and the fonts mysteriously loaded.  So my lesson for tonight is to regard Dreamweaver's design view as a potentially inaccurate sketch, and to look at things exactly where they'll be before I spend hours trying to fix something that isn't broken.  :\

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your directory path is correct and pointing to the folder your font's are in on the server.

eg

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CrimsonRoman';
    src: url('/fonts/Crimson-Roman-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/Crimson-Roman-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/Crimson-Roman-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/Crimson-Roman-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/Crimson-Roman-webfont.svg#CrimsonRoman') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: There's no path involved -- I thought that might be my problem, so I put the font files, the css sheets, and the html all in one directory, and still no dice.

Answer (score -1):

Not the answer you looking for but I really want to advice to use Cufon for this. [(Direct link to Cufon)](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)

Although @font-face is more and more supported by browsers like IE it still doesn't work perfect on each computer. 
Cufon is, as we speak, supported by:

- Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
- Internet Explorer 9 beta (as of 1.09i)
- Mozilla Firefox 1.5+
- Safari 3+
- Opera 9.5+ (9.01+ as of 1.10)
- Google Chrome 1.0+
- iOS 2.0+
- Opera Mini (to a certain degree)

...and gives next to that way more cool font-options.